# instantiate subclass by string na C#

Tags: c#

I have a Class and a Sub Clas

```
namespace MyCode
{
    public class Class1
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        public class SubClass1
        {
            int a = 1;
            int b = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to instantiate each class by string name. I can do this from the class, but not for the subclass.

This works:

```
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyCode." + "Class1"));
```

But this, din´t work:

```
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyCode." + "Class1.SubClass1"));
```

What I need to do for the second option?

Comment: what is the value of typeof(MyCode.Class1.SubClass1).FullName ?

Comment: Creating a nested public class is generally a bad practice. Can you explain your use case it's likely you've made a wrong turn.

Comment: There is [`GetNestedType`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/493773/1997232) method too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you don't know what a name should be you can see the name by checking `typeof(MyCode.Class1.SubClass1).FullName`.

When you have a subclass you use the `+` sign.

```
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyCode." + "Class1+SubClass1"));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyCode.Class1+SubClass1"));
```

Its `+` when dealing with nested types, not `.`